# Can contracts access the block header extraData field?

Tags: block-header

The yellow paper (see section 4.4) defines an `extraData` header field as follows:

> An arbitrary byte array containing
>   data relevant to this block. This must be 32 bytes
>   or fewer

Can contracts natively read this `extraData`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they cannot. However, it is quite simple to trustlesly verify the extraData from the past 256 blocks: simply provide the full header and make sure the hash matches the block hash

Comment: Is it possible to fetch the full header programmatically? Why do you mention the past 256 blocks specifically? Do they behave differently?

Comment: The block header is just the result from the `eth_getBlock` RPC call. Only the past 256 block headers are directly accessible to contracts

Comment: I cannot see which opcode gets the block header for contracts in the yellow paper.

Comment: Oh, no you would have to provide the block header externally

Comment: Contracts only have access to current *state*, and a few other useful things. Things like extraData or txHashes are not available in the EVM

Comment: I don't get it. Why the 256 block header restriction if I can provide any block header externally?

Comment: Because in order for the contract to check that the header is correct, it needs to hash it and compare that with the block hash. Only the last 256 block hashes are available from inside the EVM